# Mysql GROUP BY and ORDER BY DESC

Tags: php, mysql, sql, group-by, sql-order-by

This is my full query:

```
SELECT * FROM `clientgroupassign`
LEFT JOIN `clients` ON `clientgroupassign`.clientId = `clients`.clientId
LEFT JOIN `users` ON `carerId` = `userId`
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT * FROM 
        (SELECT * FROM `contacts` WHERE `contactGroup` = 4 ORDER BY `contactId` DESC) 
        as `contacts` 
    GROUP BY (`contactClientId`)
    )  AS `contacts` ON `contactClientId` = `clients`.clientId
WHERE groupId = 4
ORDER BY `clients`.clientId
```

There is a problem with third join causing the script to execute for about 1 minute. When I run it separattly in PMA:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM `contacts` WHERE `contactGroup` = 4 ORDER BY `contactId` DESC) AS `contacts` GROUP BY (`contactClientId`)
```

it still gets very long to execute.

What I want is to get one, last added row from `contacts` for each client who is in the group 4(client can be in various groups).

Thanks.

Comment: What does `DESCRIBE` / `EXPLAIN` show for that query ?

Comment: Also, remove `SELECT * ...` from there. Select specific columns. It might add overhead. `SELECT *` might be a real speed killer.

Answer (score 6):

To get "last added row from contacts for each client who is in the group 4" try this:

```
SELECT
    c.*
FROM(
    SELECT
        contactClientId,
        MAX(contactId) as cid
    FROM
        contacts
    WHERE
        contactGroup = 4
    GROUP BY
        contactClientId
    ORDER BY
        NULL
) as tmp
INNER JOIN contacts as c
    ON c.contactId = tmp.cid
    AND c.contactClientId = tmp.contactClientId
```

If `contactId` is PK in `contacts` then the second join clause is not needed.

> By default, MySQL sorts all GROUP BY col1, col2, ... queries as if you
>   specified ORDER BY col1, col2, ... in the query as well. If you
>   include an ORDER BY clause explicitly that contains the same column
>   list, MySQL optimizes it away without any speed penalty, although the
>   sorting still occurs. If a query includes GROUP BY but you want to
>   avoid the overhead of sorting the result, you can suppress sorting by
>   specifying ORDER BY NULL.

The complete [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html).

Full query:

```
SELECT * FROM `clientgroupassign`
LEFT JOIN `clients` ON `clientgroupassign`.clientId = `clients`.clientId
LEFT JOIN `users` ON `carerId` = `userId`
LEFT JOIN 
    (
        SELECT
            c.*
        FROM(
            SELECT
                contactClientId,
                MAX(contactId) as cid
            FROM
                contacts
            WHERE
                contactGroup = 4
            GROUP BY
                contactClientId
            ORDER BY
                NULL
        ) as tmp
        INNER JOIN contacts as c
            ON c.contactId = tmp.cid
            AND c.contactClientId = tmp.contactClientId 
    )  AS `contacts` ON `contactClientId` = `clients`.clientId
WHERE groupId = 4
ORDER BY `clients`.clientId
```

Comment: What is the point in `ORDER BY NULL`?

Comment: @GarethD its an optimization , basically filesort will not be used when grouping the data

Comment: @CORRUPT sorry about the typo, fixed now, thx

Comment: Every day is a school day! I think it is bizarre, but there you go, it is still something new I've learnt. Thanks.

Comment: @GarethD that's why i love stackoverflow because you learn something new each day :D

Comment: @Stephan thanks, it works great separetly, but how do I attach it to the main query in the place of third JOIN?

Comment: @user2104742 i posted the full query pls check it out